# Use conditions with *ngFor in ion-select

Tags: angular, angular6, ngfor, ionic4, angular-ng-if

i'm new to Angular 6 and Ionic 5 but currently learning.
Im facing a issue with my select component, i have this json:

```
 {
   "Error":200,
   "Cliente":1,
   "Nombre":"Antonio Galdamez Castillo",
   "SaldoPuntos":"156.000000",
   "Premios":[
      {
         "IdPremio":"1",
         "Premio":" $1 (UN Dolar) Mecaderia",
         "Puntos":"10",
         "TipoPremio":"Premio Propio",
         "Disponible":"1",
         "Empresa":"FABIOS BOUTIQUE"
      },
      {
         "IdPremio":"2",
         "Premio":" $5 (Cinco US Dolares) Mercaderia",
         "Puntos":"50",
         "TipoPremio":"Premio Propio",
         "Disponible":"1",
         "Empresa":"FABIOS BOUTIQUE"
      },
      {
         "IdPremio":"3",
         "Premio":" $10 (Diez US Dolares) Mercaderia",
         "Puntos":"100",
         "TipoPremio":"Premio Propio",
         "Disponible":"1",
         "Empresa":"FABIOS BOUTIQUE"
      },
      {
         "IdPremio":"4",
         "Premio":"$20 (Veinte US Dolares) Mecaderia",
         "Puntos":"200",
         "TipoPremio":"Premio Propio",
         "Disponible":"0",
         "Empresa":"FABIOS BOUTIQUE"
      },
      {
         "IdPremio":"7",
         "Premio":"$50 (Cincuenta US Dolares) Mercaderia",
         "Puntos":"500",
         "TipoPremio":"Premio Propio",
         "Disponible":"0",
         "Empresa":"FABIOS BOUTIQUE"
      },
      {
         "IdPremio":"8",
         "Premio":"$100 (Cien US Dolares) Mercaderia",
         "Puntos":"1000",
         "TipoPremio":"Premio Propio",
         "Disponible":"0",
         "Empresa":"FABIOS BOUTIQUE"
      },
      {
         "IdPremio":"9",
         "Premio":"$200 (Doscientos US Dolares) Mercaderia",
         "Puntos":"2000",
         "TipoPremio":"Premio Propio",
         "Disponible":"0",
         "Empresa":"FABIOS BOUTIQUE"
      }
   ]
}
```

And i have this on my Html file:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Premios</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="premio" ok-text="Seleccionar" cancel-text="Cancelar" >
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let article of data?.Premios" value="{{article.IdPremio}}">{{article.Premio}}</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

I cant seem to find how to display in select the Premios that has Disponible = 1.
I've tried the *ngIf but apparently i cant use them together.
I've seen some forums that says i should do the conditioning on my TS and then pass the "clean" json to my html but i'm not sure how to do it or if is it even possible to do it on my Html file.
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking for select-option?
`<ion-select-option *ngFor="let article of data?.Premios" value="{{article.IdPremio}}">{{article.Premio}}</ion-select-option>`
Here to show only article that article.Disponsible ?

Comment: Yes, i want to show in the dropdown the articles that has Disponible = 1 in json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'disponiblePipe',
})
export class DisponiblePipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(data: any[]) {
        return data.filter(article => article.Disponible == "1");
    }

}
```

Like this

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Premios</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="premio" ok-text="Seleccionar" cancel-text="Cancelar" >
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let article of data?.Premios | disponiblePipe" value="{{article.IdPremio}}">{{article.Premio}}</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

check angular docs https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Answer (score 4):

For this thing you can always use ng-container, that container is not rendering in DOM, but will help you to do some type of ngfor and ngif together. Not tested but this should work for you.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Premios</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="premio" ok-text="Seleccionar" cancel-text="Cancelar">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let article of data?.Premios | disponiblePipe">
        <ion-select-option *ngIf="article. Disponsible" value="{{article.IdPremio}}">{{article.Premio}}</ion-select-option>
    </ng-container>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: This worked too, easier approach than pipes but both worked great. THANKS